# Why file_put_contents don't really update the file when you running the script via another script?

Tags: php, curl, file-put-contents

I want one script (wrapper) run another script (file_writer) that changes an output file, but it works only when i run target script only:

**file_writer.php:**

```
<?php
    $file_name = 'output.js';
    $bytes_writen = file_put_contents($file_name,'test');
    $filemtime = date('d/m/Y H:i:s',filemtime($file_name));
    echo "$file_name updated at $filemtime. $bytes_writen bytes has been written.";
?>
```

**file_writer_wrapper.php:**

```
<?php 
die (curl_get_contents('https://example.com/file_writer.php'));
    function curl_get_contents($url)
        {
         $ch = curl_init($url);
         $data = curl_exec($ch);
         curl_close($ch);
         return $data;
        }
    ?>
```

output.js permisions: 0777

Comment: I would test `$bytes_writen` to not be `false`. i.e. `$bytes_writen !== false`.

Comment: it's never false

Comment: Why is there no debugging whatsoever around your curl call? That you check what errors cURL might have returned is the absolutely minimum, so do that and report back.

Comment: I wrote the code. You can run it and see the result. Please add debugging as you wish. Curl don't return errors in this case.

when I run file_writer_wrapper.php i get: "output.js updated at 04/04/2018 08:12:52. 4 bytes has been written.1"

when I run file_writer.php i get: "output.js updated at 04/04/2018 08:14:35. 4 bytes has been written."

The char '1' is the different between the outputs.